# Export Database from Google Cloud Sql to external Database

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to export my database created in Google Cloud Sql and import it into a new external server.

I tried to create a sql backup through the google console, downloaded it and copied it to the new server via filezilla and then launched the following command:

```
psql -U postgres -d ciclods-db -1 -f Backup-db_Cloud_SQL_Export_2019-03-23\ \(17_01_19\)
```

but i get this output:

> ERROR:  role "cloudsqladmin" does not exist
> REVOKE
>
> ERROR:  role
> "cloudsqlsuperuser" does not exist GRANT

what is the right procedure to follow in these cases?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution.

Comment: I had the same issue and I just deleted these two lines from my script so I imported with success. I know that it is not the best to do however I just wanted to load the script in my machine to take a look into the data. Worked for my scenario.

Comment: faceing the same problem. Did anyone find solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the same problem by locating and deleting the two lines from the exported sql file with "cloudsqladmin". My app does not use it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my SQL file was around 10 GB. Hence, it wasn't possible to remove these two lines directly using the convention text editor. After searching around, I found that I could use [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to remove them. Here is the command:

```
sed '/cloudsqladmin\|cloudsqlsuperuser/d' backup.sql > fixedbackup.sql
```

Answer (score -3):

to do this task you can follow the official GCP guide about How to export data from Cloud SQL[1] in that document they give you the option to export the data into a dump file or csv files which can be used for other tools.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting

Comment: yes but that file export roles that not exist and this raise an error->  ERROR:  role "cloudsqladmin" does not exist
REVOKE

Answer (score -3):

In order to create the export file, you have to do it from a command line and use additional flags. As per documentation‘s “[Exporting data to a SQL dump file](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting#external-server)”, there is a section on *Exporting data from an externally-managed database server*.

As well you can find there the option to export the data into a CSV file.